# Tensor to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, keras, tensor

I need to convert the Tensorflow tensor passed to my custom loss function into a numpy array, make some changes and convert it back to a tensor. I read some answers suggesting the use of eval() function after calling the tensorflow session, but I need to make this conversion in the loss function. How should I go about this?

```python
def loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
     #obtain y_true_np and y_pred_np - How to do this?
     #make changes to array
     #convert back using backend.variable()
```

EDIT: Tried out the code below:

```python
def loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
 #obtain y_true_np and y_pred_np - How to do this?
 y_true_np = K.eval(y_true)
 y_pred_np = K.eval(y_pred)
 # make changes to numpy arrays
 # obtain modified numpy arrays as y_true_mod & y_pred_mod 
 # convert back to tensors using backend.variable()
 out_true = K.variable(y_true_mod)
 out_pred = K.variable(y_pred_mod)
 # continue to define your custom loss with out_true & out_pred...
```

But I get an error in the following line:

```python
y_true_np = K.eval(y_true)
```

error message:

```python
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'out_layer_target' with dtype float     

[[Node: out_layer_target = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

where out_layer is the name of my final convolutional layer(output layer as well)

EDIT2: I apologise for the confusion

I am training a fully convolutional model from scratch

Input size - 720x560x1

Output size - 640x480x3

So my code is as follows:

```python
#Define loss function as above
def loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    #obtain y_true_np and y_pred_np - How to do this?
    y_true_np = K.eval(y_true)
    y_pred_np = K.eval(y_pred)
    # make changes to numpy arrays
    # obtain modified numpy arrays as y_true_mod & y_pred_mod 
    # convert back to tensors using backend.variable()
    out_true = K.variable(y_true_mod)
    out_pred = K.variable(y_pred_mod)
    # continue to define your custom loss with out_true & out_pred
    #return loss calculated using the tensors

#main
#define model
input_layer = Input(shape = (None, None, 1), name='input_layer')
x = something()(input_layer)
...
out_layer = Conv2D(3, (9, 9), strides = 1, padding = 'same', activation = 'tanh', name='out_layer', kernel_initializer=weights_init)(x)


model = Model(input = [input_layer], output = [out_layer])
model.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), loss = [loss_fn], metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

So the error is actually during model.compile() which is due to the below line in function loss_fn:

```python
y_true_np = K.eval(y_true)
```

I have not yet started training using model.fit() and therefore, there is no training data fed into memory. I was looking to check if the model compiles with 0 errors. I hope this info helps.

Error message:

```python
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'out_layer_target' with dtype float 

[[Node: out_layer_target = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

EDIT3:

This is a small piece of code I wrote that can be reproduced to get the same error.

```python
import numpy as np
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.models import *
from keras.layers import *
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam
from keras import backend as K

sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
K.set_session(sess)


def loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_np =  K.eval(y_true) #y_true.eval(session=sess)
    loss = K.Variable(0.)
    return loss

input_layer = Input(shape = (560, 720, 1), name='input_layer')
x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1, name='BN')(input_layer)
out_layer = Conv2D(3, (9, 9), strides = 1, padding = 'same', activation = 'tanh', name='out_layer')(x)

model = Model(inputs=[input_layer], outputs=[out_layer])
print(model.summary())
model.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), loss = [loss_fn], metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I get the same error with this simple model as well. You can use this entire snippet to reproduce the error.

Comment: normally, `y_true` would be the true *labels*, taken directly from the training set, and not the result of some CNN output (that would be `y_pred`); moreover, as I have clearly stated in my answer, I am assuming that both `y_true` and `y_pred` are *tensors*, which you would like transformed to numpy arrays - if this is not the case, please provide more detailed info in order to be able to help you...

Comment: I think what you are looking for is tf.pyfunc() but it is really unclear what you are asking even after your edit.

Comment: If you want your operation to be at the same time in numpy and differentiable you will run into troubles but all the necessary steps can be found on stack.

Comment: Yes, I basically need to modify the shape of the tensor and offset each channel of the output(3 channeled output) by a certain value. It's two lines using numpy, so I was looking to convert y_true and y_pred to numpy arrays.

Comment: You mean the code is *actually* like that? You don't have complemented my `loss_fn` template with what modifications you want, and returned the actual desired loss function??

Comment: No, I have left those details out, because they seem irrelevant and the error is due to the first line in the function.

Comment: You cannot do that. You will lose the graph connection and it will be impossible for the system to calculate gradients.

Comment: If you explain what the changes you want are, there may be a way to do them with keras backend or with tensorflow/theano functions

Comment: I need to reshape the tensor from 480x640x3 to 1x480x640x3, and perform arithmetic operations on each of the channels - [:, :, :, 0], [:, :, :, 1] and [:, :, :, 2]